# In Massachusetts, does my church need a permit in order to sacrifice animals?

Tags: constitutional-law, massachusetts, religion, animals

I know a while back ago, the Supreme court decided that it is unconstitutional for states to make animal sacrifice illegal.

> Church of the Lukumi Babalu Aye, Inc. v. Hialeah, 508 U.S. 520 (1993), was a case in which the Supreme Court of the United States held that an ordinance passed in Hialeah, Florida, forbidding the "unnecessar[y]" killing of "an animal in a public or private ritual or ceremony not for the primary purpose of food consumption", was unconstitutional.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_of_the_Lukumi_Babalu_Aye_v._City_of_Hialeah

But is it constitutional for states to require a permit to practice animal sacrifice? If so, does Massachusetts require my church to get a permit for animal sacrifice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same principles as articulated in Church of the Lukumi Babalu Aye also prohibit requiring a permit, since a permit implies the possibility of denying permission, and they cannot deny permission to practice your religion. See [Watchtower Bible & Tract Society of New York, Inc. v. Village of Stratton](https://caselaw.findlaw.com/us-supreme-court/536/150.html), 536 U.S. 150. In general, the practice of religion cannot be regulated, though of course human sacrifice can be because it follows directly from statutes against murder (there are no *separate* laws against human sacrifice for religious purposes).

Comment: Animal cruelty laws?

Comment: Not applicable to humane animal sacrifice. We will have to see what happens, if there's a religious case where animal torture is required. Animal sacrifice is not illegal under cruelty laws.